# Regex to extract and format part of URL

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract `p5925` and `c98` of the following URL:

`http://www.example.com/mens-shoes/mens-boots/p5925/c98/colour/Black`

The format I want is:

`p:5925`, `c:98`

The regex I got now is `([^pc]\d+)` which matches just the numbers but not sure how I can get it in the format I wanted.

I used the code `preg_match('/([^pc]\d+)/', $ls_url, $la_matches);` to split it.

Comment: parse_url will not extract the portion of path for me. I have to anyways regex search after parse_url.

Comment: Thanks, but then how would I get `5925` from `p5925` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=/)([pc])(\d+)(?=/)~', $ls_url, $la_matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('~\b([pc])(\d+)\b~', $ls_url, $la_matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4wM0/1)

Comment: Thanks that works fine. If I have to get /colour/Black bit too as array how would I change the regex ?

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => p5925
            [1] => c98
            [2] => colour/Black
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => p
            [1] => c
            [2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5925
            [1] => 98
            [2] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => colour/Black
        )

)`

Comment: Thanks Can it be like p and c split into values ? at the moment its colour/Black. So the second array will be p, c, colour and third array will be 5925, 98, Black

Comment: Thats perfect (thumbsup)